# Electron with React- trying to import ipcRenderer - preload.js is not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, ipc

I'm trying to send data fron the page to electron using ipc
When I run the elctron app, the window.ipcRenderer is just undifined(inside the electron app)

this is the code

main.js:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1080,
    height: 920,
    fullscreenable: false,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })
```

.

```
ipcMain.on("play-vlc-magnet", (event, magnet) => {
  //run_script("webtorrent --vlc " + magnet)
  console.log("recevied:", magnet)
})
```

preload.js(the console.log won't be in the console):

```
console.log("running preload")
window.ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
```

line which is being called inside a react componenet:

```
  window.ipcRenderer.send("play-vlc-magnet", r.data)
```

element inside React(which writes "ipc doesn't exist")

```
 <p>{(typeof window.ipcRenderer !== "undefined") ? "ipc renderer exists" : "ipc doesn't exist"</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Understanding and implementing a working `preload.js` script can be hard.

In the past I found it best to read and re-read the below points until you understand the difference between the main and render processes, what and why a `preload.js` script is used and how to implement and interact with a working `preload.js` script. After that, the sky is the limit.

- [Process model](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#preload-scripts)
- [Context Bridge](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge)
- [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc)
- [ipcMain](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main)
- [ipcRender](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer)

It is common practice (as shown in the Electron documentation) to implement concrete functions within your `preload.js` script. Whilst there is nothing wrong with this approach I believe it can be easily confusing when trying to initially understand and use this approach.

Instead, my personal approach is to use only one `preload.js` script and code it for the transport of data via the use of whitelisted channel names only. This allows me to:

1. Use only one `preload.js` script for all windows I create.
2. Define in one place a master list of all whitelisted channel names.
3. Have a small `preload.js` script file size, void of concrete implementations.
4. Separate concerns and place the implementation of concrete function back into their proper (main and render process) domains.

In the code snippets below, I have show both the 'common' method programmers are shown in the Electron documentation and the alternative method I commonly use. You can decide which best suits your understanding and coding style.

---

Let's start with a working `preload.js` script, which is the part preventing you from communicating between your render process and the main process.

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
const {contextBridge, ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'electronAPI', {
        playVlcMagnet: (data) => ipcRenderer.send('play-vlc-magnet', data)
    }
)
```

---

As an alternative to the above 'common' `preload.js` script, below is my personal preference.

`preload-alt.js` (main process)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [
            'play-vlc-magnet' // Channel name
        ],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

And how to use it.

```js
/**
 * Render --> Main
 * ---------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Main:    ipcMain.on('channel', (event, data) => { methodName(data); })
 *
 * Main --> Render
 * ---------------
 * Main:    windowName.webContents.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.receive('channel', (data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Value) --> Render
 * ----------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.invoke('channel', data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Main:    ipcMain.handle('channel', (event, data) => { return someMethod(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Promise) --> Render
 * ------------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.invoke('channel', data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Main:    ipcMain.handle('channel', async (event, data) => {
 *              return await promiseName(data)
 *                  .then(() => { return result; })
 *          });
 */
```

---

Next, is your `main.js` file which you appear to have implemented correctly.

`main.js` (main process)

```js
const app = require('electron').app;
const browserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const path = require('path');

let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new browserWindow({
        width: 1080,
        height: 920,
        fullscreenable: false,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false, // Default is false
            contextIsolation: true, // Default is true
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')  // Use of preload.js
            // preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload-alt.js')  // Use of preload-alt.js
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

app.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (browserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

ipcMain.on("play-vlc-magnet", (event, magnet) => {
    // run_script("webtorrent --vlc " + magnet)
    console.log("received: ", magnet)
})
```

---

Lastly, your `index.html` file, which I do not have the code for, but you will get the idea.

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Play VLC Magnet">
    </body>

    <script>
        let data = 'This is my data';

        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.electronAPI.playVlcMagnet(data); // Use of preload.js
            // window.ipcRender.send('play-vlc-magnet', data); // Use of preload-alt.js
        })
    </script>
</html>
```