# How to access a variable in Electron JS from different file, after clicking the button?

Tags: javascript, electron

I would like to know how to access a variable from different file in Electron JS.
When I run the application, I'd like to select a file path through the input field. It works. After clicking the button (and having already selected the path beforehand) I would like to send this path to a function in another file.

I tried to export the path but it doesn't work. Please help. I am attaching the file main.js, and algorithm.js. I would like to import results from main.js to algorithm.js on button click.

```
/*This is algorithm.js*/
/*const { path } = require('main.js')

function getPath(path) {
    document.getElementById("toinject").innerHTML = path;
    console.log(path)

}*/

var fs = require("fs");
const readline = require('readline');
async function processLineByLine() {
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("output.txt");
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('./kat.txt');

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fileStream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });
       
    for await (const line of rl) {
        // Each line in input.txt will be successively available here as `line`.
        console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
        var new_line = deletefromBracket(line)
        writeStream.write(new_line + "\n");
    }
    writeStream.end();
    }


function deletefromBracket(str) {
    var indexOfLeftBracket = str.indexOf('(')
    str = str.substring(0, indexOfLeftBracket-1)
    return str;
}
```

```
/*This is main.js from electron*/
const { app, BrowserWindow, dialog, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
let win;
function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function() {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (win === null) createWindow()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
ipcMain.on('select-dirs', async (event, arg) => {
  const result = await dialog.showOpenDialog(win, {
    properties: ['openFile']
  })
  console.log('directories selected', result.filePaths)
  let path = result.filePaths;
  module.exports = { path };
})
```

Comment: The path you are trying to 'export', are you wanting to send it to another file in the main process or to a render process?

Comment: To a render process

Answer (score 0):

To move data between Electron renders you will need to use [IPC (Inter-Process Communication)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) and your `preload.js` script. Exporting and Importing variables between processed does not work.

Reading the below topics in detail will take you a long way in understanding how an Electron application communicates between processes, in this case your main process and two render processes.

- [Process Model](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model)
- [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc)
- [Using Preload Scripts](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload)
- [Context Isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation)
- [Process Sandboxing](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc)

In relation to your question, your objective would be to:

1. Send a signal from your render process to your main process to open a file dialog.
2. Send a signal from your main process to your other render process, along with the selected path.

Within your `main.js` file there is no need to use `async` / `await` as we can direct the dialog's (promised) output straight into the IPC method (to communicate with the second render process).

Please see the below minimum reproducible example for how to communicate between processes and the use of a `preload.js` script.

> PS: If functionality of the `preload.js` script is difficult to understand, see [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72157098/2627338) which offers a different type of approach.

---

`main.js` (main process)

Within this `main.js` file we open two windows for testing purposes. The primary window will have the `Open File Dialog` button and the secondary window will display the selected path.

Upon receiving an IPC `open-dialog` message, open the file dialog. Once a path has been selected, send the path via IPC to the secondary window.

```js
// Import required electron modules
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronDialog = require('electron').dialog;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

// Import required Node modules
const nodePath = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection
let primaryWindow;
let secondaryWindow;

function createPrimaryWindow() {
    const primaryWindow = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            sandbox: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    primaryWindow.loadFile(nodePath.join(__dirname, 'primary-window.html'))
        .then(() => { primaryWindow.show(); });

    return primaryWindow;
}

function createSecondaryWindow() {
    const secondaryWindow = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 410,
        y: 0,
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        parent: primaryWindow, // Child of the primary window
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            sandbox: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    secondaryWindow.loadFile(nodePath.join(__dirname, 'secondary-window.html'))
        .then(() => { secondaryWindow.show(); });

    return secondaryWindow;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    primaryWindow = createPrimaryWindow();
    secondaryWindow = createSecondaryWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createPrimaryWindow();
    }
});

// ---

electronIpcMain.on('open-dialog', () => {
    electronDialog.showOpenDialog(primaryWindow, {properties: ['openFile']})
        .then((result) => {
            // Bail early if user cancels dialog
            if (result.canceled) {
                console.log('User cancelled / closed dialog');
            } else {
                secondaryWindow.webContents.send('send-path', result.filePaths[0]);
                console.log(result.filePaths[0]);
            }
        })
})
```

---

`preload.js` (main process)

Create the IPC message paths between the main process and render processes.

```js
// Import the necessary Electron modules
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// Exposed protected methods in the render process
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods
    'ipcRenderer', {
        // From main to render
        sendPath: (listener) => {
            ipcRenderer.on('send-path', listener);
        },
        // From render to main
        openDialog: () => {
            ipcRenderer.send('open-dialog');
        }
    }
);
```

And how to use it...

```txt
/**
 *
 * Main --> Render
 * ---------------
 * Main:    window.webContents.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Preload: apiName: (listener) => { ipcRenderer.on('channel', listener); }
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.apiName((event, data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Main --> Render (Once)
 * ----------------------
 * Main:    window.webContents.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Preload: apiName: (listener) => { ipcRenderer.once('channel', listener); }
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.apiName((event, data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main
 * ---------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.apiName(data); // Data is optional.
 * Preload: apiName: (data) => { ipcRenderer.send('channel', data) }
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.on('channel', (event, data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Once)
 * ----------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.apiName(data); // Data is optional.
 * Preload: apiName: (data) => { ipcRenderer.send('channel', data); }
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.once('channel', (event, data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Value) --> Render
 * ----------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.apiName(data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Preload: apiName: (data) => { return ipcRenderer.invoke('channel', data); }
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', (event, data) => { return someMethod(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Promise) --> Render
 * ------------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.apiName(data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Preload: apiName: (data) => { return ipcRenderer.invoke('channel', data); }
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', async (event, data) => {
 *              return await myPromise(data).then((result) => { return result; })
 *          });
 *
 * Main:    function myPromise(data) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... }; )};
 *
 */
```

---

`primary-window.html` (render process)

Upon the `button` being clicked, send an IPC message to the main process to open the file dialog.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Primary Window</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Primary Window</h1>
        <hr>
        <input type="button" id="openDialog" value="Open File Dialog">
    </body>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('openDialog').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.ipcRenderer.openDialog();
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

`secondary-window.html` (render process)

Upon receiving an IPC message from the main process, display and log the selected file path.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Secondary Window</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Secondary Window</h1>
        <hr>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </body>

    <script>
        window.ipcRenderer.sendPath((event, data) => {
            document.getElementById('output').innerText = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
    </script>
</html>
```