# How use node_modules when textisolation true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, requirejs, electron-builder

I am currently making an application with Electron but when I package my application I have a white screen when I set the parameter `textisolation: true`.

But when I set it to `false` my modules like `jquery` or `sqlite3` are not defined.

Here are three pieces of code:

main.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const { app, BrowserWindow, screen } = require('electron')
const EventEmitter = require('events')
app.commandLine.appendSwitch("ignore-certificate-errors");
const loadingEvents = new EventEmitter()
let win
app.on('ready', () => {  
  const { width, height } = screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize
  window = new BrowserWindow({
    width,
    height,
    minWidth:970,
    minHeight:390,
    icon: 'icon.png',
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
      webSecurity: false,
    }
  })
  
  window.loadFile((path.join(__dirname, '/html/loading.html')))

  // Our loadingEvents object listens for 'finished'
  loadingEvents.on('finished', () => {
    window.loadFile((path.join(__dirname, '/html/index.html')))
    window.webContents.openDevTools()
  })

  setTimeout(() => loadingEvents.emit('finished'), 5000)
})
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" type="text/css">
    <title>MyApp</title>
  </head>
  <body class="container">
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a id="name">MyApp</a>
      <a href='index.html'>Home</a>
      <a href='get.html'>Live TV</a>
      <a href='post.html'>Movies</a>
      <a href='inline.html'>Series</a>
      </a>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="../js/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

index.js

```js
const { get } = require('jquery');
var $ = jQuery = require("jquery")
var mysql = require('mysql');
var sq = require('sqlite3');
require('dotenv').config()
```

I tried several solutions but unfortunately without success.

Do you know a way to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I think I found the beginning of a solution.
please let me know if i am going in the wrong direction.

preloads.js
'
const { contextBridge } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('versions', {
  get: () =>  require('jquery'),
  $: () => jQuery = require("jquery"),
  mysql: () =>  require('mysql'),
  sq: () => require('sqlite3'),
  dotenv: () => require('dotenv').config(),
  node: () => process.versions.node,
  chrome: () => process.versions.chrome,
  electron: () => process.versions.electron,
  directory: () => __dirname
})'

Comment: Do you mean `textIsolation` or `contextIsolation`? Additionally, within your `main.js` file, you declare `win`, but refer Electron's instance methods to `window`? Lastly, `enableRemoteModule` has not been available since Electron v14. What version of Electron are you running? Your `package.json` file will tell you this.

Comment: Unless you are doing something very specific with jQuery that cannot be replicated with native browser Javascript functions, there is a good chance you may not need it.

Comment: Have you considered moving your require statements into the main process. This will allow your render process to run much faster and not lock-up your UI. Additionally, you can communicate with these Node.js modules via IPC (your `preload.js` script).

Comment: You are definately moving in the right direction. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72157098/2627338) may shed a bit more light on how a `preload.js` script can work.